# How to create F# .Net Core ConsoleApp in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: f#, .net-core, csproj, visual-studio-2017

`project.json` is gone and I don't quite understand how to change compiler(language) for the project. Creating of `Console Application (.Net Core)` leads to actually new C# project with refreshed `.csproj` file with `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>`.

How can I create F# Console Application with targeting to `netcoreapp1.0` with Visual Studio 2017 RC?

Comment: but you still can use command line: dotnet new -l F#

Comment: @Alex I can't build project in CLI the project it creates and can't open it in VS2017 RC

Comment: but the same is for VS2015, there is no F# core project template

Comment: @KovpaevAlexey Using `dotnet build` on the project created from CLI should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tooling for .NET Core is still in "beta" level stages (and that's being generous, even for C#), and the for F#, it's not even quite to that level.

At this point (just post first RC "refresh"), using the command line (`dotnet new`) is pretty much the best option.  Each 2017 RC update is improving this situation, but the F# situation within Visual Studio tooling is not to the level of working like normal .NET projects at this point.  Supposedly, this will work as expected by RTM, but it's just not there today.